# Nativescript action dialog requires I click an option twice before the dialog closes

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

*ANSWERED*
I'm using the built in Nativescript action dialog module and I'm running into an issue where I must click an option twice before the dialog box closes. Each time I click an option, the option fires but does not close for the second time. To even close the dialog box by pressing cancel, I have to press cancel twice before it will close.

I've googled this but other people don't seem to have this problem. I looked through the API and documentation for Nativescript dialogs but it didn't provide much insight into what causes the dialog to close or how it closes/cancels.

```html
<app-action-button text="move rooms"
                   (tap)="onMoveRoomTap()></app-action-button>
```

```js
onMoveRoomTap(){
  if (this.rooms.length !==0) {
    const options = {
      title: 'Move Room',
      cancelButtonText: 'Cancel,
      actions: this.rooms.map((object) => object.name), };

    action(options).then((result) => {
      if (result !== 'Cancel') {
        const actionData = {data_for_api_call};
        this.api.post('api_name', actioinData).subscribe(() => {
          getInventories();
          Toast.makeText('Move Room Completed!').show(); },
        (error) => {
           console.log(error); });
      }
    });
  } else {
    console.log('No rooms to move to');
  }
}
```

Where this.api is part of an api service, this.rooms is a list of rooms that is called from the API. And the action button is part of a page that displays an inventory item, so getInventories() makes an api call that gets the inventory information now with the new room name.

When i click the action button a dialog box appears with a list of all the rooms, a title displaying 'Move Rooms', and a cancel button that says 'Cancel'. In addition, the first I click a room, it successfully moves the room and displays the toast, however, the dialog doesn't disappear. when i click it a second time, the room successfully moves and the toast appears and the dialog closes. In addition, if I click cancel, nothing will will happen if it's after the first click, but it will cancel after the second click. If press cancel on the first click but a room on the second click, I will successfully move rooms and same if i click the rooms first and cancel second.
What do I have to do to get the dialog to close after the first click.

Here is the QR code for a playground with the same problem.
[Nativescript Playground QR code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztVOz.png)

Comment: is it possible for you to create a playground?

Comment: Sounds something specific to your code / use case, please share a Playground Sample where the issue could be reproduced.

Comment: I created a playground and added the QR code for it to the end of the question

Answer (score 0):

Try to this code for dialog box.

```
import * as dialogs from "tns-core-modules/ui/dialogs";

clickOnOpenDialog() {
    dialogs.action({
        message: "Your message",
        cancelButtonText: "Cancel text",
        actions: ["Option1", "Option2"]
    }).then((result) => {
        console.log("Dialog result: " + result);
        if (result == "Options1") {
            //Do action1
        } else if (result == "Option2") {
            //Do action2
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I replaced my code for the action dialog with this and I still have the same problem. I created a playground and added the QR code for it to the bottom of the question if you want to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:
The button used was a custom component called action-button, which took in text, an icon and a function and displayed them as a label. The function was called using @Output and an event emitter. It looked like action-button.component.ts:

```js
@Output() tap = new EventEmitter();
```

action-button.component.html:

```html
(tap)="tap.emit()"
```

home.component.html:

```html
<app-action-button icon="move"
                           *ngIf="inventories.type!=='sample' && inventories.type !=='destruction inventory'"
                           [text]="'scan.detail.moveRooms' | L"
                           (tap)="onMoveRoomsTap()"></app-action-button>
```

This caused the dialog box to be called twice when clicked, once when you click the button in the home component and another when the Event Emitter was called.
I fixed the problem by removing the event emitter so in the action-button component, tap looked like:

```js
@Input() tap: any;
```

action-button.component.html:

```html
(tap)="tap"
```